# feature selection of multivariate time series forecasting with fsMTS package

Tags: r, time-series, feature-selection

The `fsMTS` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fsMTS/fsMTS.pdf) uses the following example:

```
# Load traffic data
data(traffic.mini)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  datetime            rnd_86775 rnd_92909 rnd_87171
  <dttm>                  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 2017-07-30 00:05:00      25         0        25.5
2 2017-07-30 00:10:00      14.5       0        13  
3 2017-07-30 00:15:00      49.5      -0.5      12.5
4 2017-07-30 00:20:00      12         2        22.5
5 2017-07-30 00:25:00      19        -1        28  
6 2017-07-30 00:30:00       2.5       0         7 

# Scale and exclude the first column - it contains timestamps
data <- scale(traffic.mini$data[,-1])

# Applies random forest estimation of k linear regression models with max lag of 3
mRF<-fsMTS(data, max.lag=3, method="RF")

# Choosing most important features with sparsity threshold of 0.5
# returns a binary feature matrix. Columns correspond to components of the time series; rows correspond to lags.
cutoff(feature.set = mRF, threshold = 0.5)

             rnd_86775 rnd_92909 rnd_87171
rnd_86775.l1         0         0         1
rnd_92909.l1         1         1         0
rnd_87171.l1         0         1         1
rnd_86775.l2         1         1         0
rnd_92909.l2         0         1         1
rnd_87171.l2         0         1         0
rnd_86775.l3         0         1         0
rnd_92909.l3         0         1         0
rnd_87171.l3         1         0         1
```

How do I interpret the output of the cutoff function above? For example, if `rnd_86775` is the target feature that I want to forecast and I want a lag of 3, which one of the last three rows do I use? The row corresponding to `rnd_86775.l3` doesn't include my target feature in that case, and only indicates to select `rnd_92909.l3`.

Answer (score 1):

The cutoff function returns a 0/1 matrix by selecting a specified share (threshold) of most important features from a matrix of feature importance metrics (feature.set); 1 corresponds to a selected feature, 0 - to excluded.

In your example, the first column should be used for the required information; namely rnd_86775 can be forecasted using the first lag of rnd_92909 (rnd_92909.l1), second lag of rnd_86775 (rnd_86775.l2) and third lag of rnd_87171 (rnd_87171.l3).

Generally, the package is focused to forecasting of all components of the multivariate time series at the same time - e.g., using the vector autoregressive model:

```
fs <- cutoff(feature.set, threshold)
MTS::VAR(sampl, p=L, fixed=fs)
```

Similarly, the selected features can be used as inputs for ANN, KNN, etc.